# Dynamic web page rendering challenge

Tags: javascript

I have a page that when loaded makes additional request to the server to get JSON objects for rendering it sections. Each object has the structure

```
{partial_id:"",html:"",children:[]}
```

I need to know when all objects are collected and  rendered.
The challenge here is that some objects have children and they also need to be retrieved from the server before being rendered inside the parent object.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Put the code that allows you to render your json object inside the success callback of your server request function and all data will be ready to use

Comment: In what way you are downloading the JSON data? You can use promise pattern. Create promise which will be resolved after all of the request ended.

Comment: Take a look at this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: This is also a very good article which can give some more ideas about how to do it. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: I guess i should have mentioned it earlier. I am working on an existing project so i cannot use promises.currently a callback function is executed after each object is received and rendered.when an object with children is rendered multiple requests are sent to collect it children.

Comment: what libraries are included in project?

Comment: Its a project with jquey and underscore

Comment: jQuery `$.ajax` returns promises. Show more code related to what you are trying to do

Comment: As charlietfl said, jQuery uses promises. Other, but a little bit silly way, is to make the request synchronous.